# Implicit pointer variable with another in auto definition

Tags: c++, auto

Why is it not possible to define an implicit type modifier `*` (pointer) together with another variable of the same *base type*?

```
int i = 1;
auto ip = &i;   // fine
auto *ip2 = &i; // fine

// error: inconsistent deduction for ‘auto’: ‘int*’ and then ‘int’
// auto ip3 = &i, ir = i; 
// auto ip4 = &i, ival = i;

auto *ip5 = &i, &ir2 = i;   // fine
auto *ip6 = &i, &ival2 = i; // fine
```

I generally prefer more explicit code and usage of `*` and `&` to increase readability and intentions. Here I would even define one variable per line.   But in this case I wonder why the implicit usage of a different *type modifier* for the *base type* doesn't work in case of `ip3` and `ip4`.

Is that a safety measure or a constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "base type" in the context in which you're trying to use it; `int*` is a different type from `int`, period.

`auto` must "resolve" to the same type in the whole multi-variable declaration, otherwise it's often ambiguous as to which one you wanted (think about conversions).

Comment: I especially like your 'period' thing and it is ambiguous. The C++ Primer mentioned the base type, so I focused on that. Will accept your answer in nine minutes, stackoverflow says I have to be patient ;)